# При работе с БД Ошибка: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, telegram-bot, telegram

Я не могу разобраться как работать с БД. Постоянно какие-то ошибки и я не понимаю, в чем они.

Кому не сложно, сделайте так, чтоб создавалась БД SQLite3 с полями `Id` и `user_id`, куда при вводе команды `start` в `user_id` добавлялось значение переменной `user_id`.

```
import telebot
import config
import sqlite3
#from telebot import apihelper

#apihelper.proxy = {'http':'https://161.35.78.7:3128'}

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, user_id )

bot.polling()
```

UPD: Код:

```
import telebot
import config
import sqlite3
#from telebot import apihelper

#apihelper.proxy = {'https':'https://51.254.35.77:8080'}

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE users(id integer PRIMARY KEY, user_id text)')
conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш TELEGRAMM ID = " + str(user_id))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(1, 'user_id')")
    conn.commit()

conn.close()
bot.polling()
```

**Ошибка:**

> ```
> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(1, 'user_id')")
> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. 
> The object was created in thread id 10396 and this is thread id 8148.
> ```

Просто никогда не работал с БД и может быть, что ошибка глупая.

Comment: Нет уж, давайте сюда ваш код и ошибки. Надо учиться на своих ошибках, готовый код вас может ничему и не научить.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас)

Comment: @Ronnn, воспользуйтесь для вашей простоты GUI-программой SQLiteStudio. Она бесплатная и удобная, а sql-запросы можно заменить несколькими кликами мыши:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать параметр [`check_same_thread=False`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
```

Comment: Помогло, но появилась другая ошибка (. (cannot operate on a closed database)

Comment: @Ronnn, у вас в коде есть строка `conn.close()`. Она закрывает соединение с БД, поэтому появляется эта ошибка. Попробуйте пока что закомментировать, либо в функции создавайте новое подключение к БД.

Comment: @Ronnn Выделите запись в базу в отдельную функцию. И пусть она открывает коннекшен, записывает в базу и тут же закрывает коннекшен. Это более правильный путь, чем держать открытым коннекшен непонятно в каком потоке и в каком состоянии. Конечно, открытие коннекшена занимает время и хочется его сэкономить, но это неправильный шаблон работы с базой данных.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать и сделаю так =)

Comment: @CrazyElf, а почему держать открытое соединение плохая практика? Я обычно соединение держу открытым, а вот курсоры создаю индивидуально для каждого потока. Создание курсора занимает гораздо меньше времени и ресурсов по сравнению с созданием соединения.

Comment: @MaxU Не, ну в целом сильно зависит от используемого db engine, ORM (если используется) и от программы. Если ты один в базу пишешь, ресурсов мало и база не мощная, то можно всё открыть и держать, не вопрос. Но в промышленном применении обычно такое дело, что с одной стороны коннекшен может в любой момент прерваться по какой-то причине (тысячи их), а с другой стороны крупные БД сами держат пул коннекшенов и быстро их выдают по требованию (а число их всё-равно ограничено), и с теми же параметрами если повторно обратиться - так моментально выдают. Поэтому оптимально коннекшены самому не держать.

Comment: @MaxU Либо, если используется какой-нибудь ORM, так он вообще если не путаю сам с коннекшенами разбирается. И тоже шаблон работы такой, что быстро открыл контекст, считал/записал, и закрыл контекст. А если долго держишь контекст, потом ORM запутается какие данные новее в разных потоках, кэш у него распухнет от данных и т.д.