# Почему ошибка sqlite3.ProgrammingError?

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot, sqlite3

База данных:

```
import sqlite3

class SQLighter:

    def __init__(self, database):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def subscriber_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
    
    def update_subscription(self, user_id, status):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `status` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (status, user_id))
```

Бот:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from sqlighter import SQLighter
db = SQLighter('db.db')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    if (not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,' Вы успешно подписались')
```

Сама ошибка:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 9700 and this is thread id 9344
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно перевести ошибку на русский, если не знаете английского:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: объекты SQLite, созданные в потоке, могут использоваться только в том же потоке. Объект был создан в потоке с идентификатором 9700, и это поток с идентификатором 9344.

Вот другой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138549/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%91%D0%94-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-sqlite-objects-created-in-a-thread-can-only-be-used-in-t), в котором посоветовали сделать так:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
```

Впрочем нельзя чтобы к одной sqlite базе было два запроса ондовреммено, это ее покоцает. *Be careful and good luck!* ;)